# Apex Controller based on multiple selections

Tags: apex, controller

I have written the apex class controller below to pull through tasks logged against my project. What i would like to do though is 2 things.

1 - Look at tasks that are either linked to project id or the child project id
2 - Look at tasks where Milestone is ticked as True in the checkbox on the task (you will see i have reference the milestone in the fields i want to pull)

I thought the milestone part would be easy using

'where TaskRay__Project__c =: std.getRecord().Id && TASKRAY__trIsMilestone__c == 'TRUE'];

But that doesnt work.. also can i put an or option in here and just add in:

TaskRay__Project__c.Parent__Project__c =: std.getRecord().Id

Thanks

Matt

[image]

[image]

```
public class task
{
    public List<TASKRAY__Project_Task__c> task { get; set; }

    Public task( ApexPages.StandardController std )
    {
        if( std.getRecord().Id != null )
        {
            task = [ Select Id, Name, TASKRAY__trIsMilestone__c,TASKRAY__trCompleted__c,TASKRAY__trTotalTimeOnTask__c,TASKRAY__trStartDate__c,TASKRAY__Deadline__c,Owner.Name,TASKRAY__List__c,Actionable_By__c 
                      from TASKRAY__Project_Task__c 
                      where (TaskRay__Project__c =: std.getId() OR 
                             TaskRay__Project__r.TASKRAY__Project_Parent__c =: std.getId()) AND 
                            TASKRAY__trIsMilestone__c = TRUE];
        }
        else
        {
            task = new List<TASKRAY__Project_Task__c>();
        }
    }         
}
```

Comment: Would you replace your screen captures with the actual code please?Captures are very difficult to read. Your 2nd capture isn't a complete line, so has no context. Also, Is Taskray_Project__c, the project and Taskray_Project_Task__c the Task?

Comment: @crmprogdev How do i upload my code? as text its too long? And yes the project is the parent, however there may be a parent project as well and the task can relate to the parent project or the child project

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `&&` is _not_ a valid operator in SOQL (you should get a compilation error if you try to use that). If that was truly in your code, try replacing it with `AND`, and then test it out and edit your question with your findings.

Comment: Thanks @Derek i have changed to AND and = TRUE which has saved with no errors. I will try the same with the OR function

Comment: @MatthewBracewell `OR` function? I don't see any mention of an `OR` in your question. It sounds like you have additional information that could be useful to know (for providing a correct and accurate answer). If you have additional code, please [edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/158138/edit) to include it. Also, if you copy/paste a code block into a question (or an answer), putting 4 spaces at the start of every line formats it as a 'code block' which makes it easier to read. The quick way to do that is to highlight your code, and click the `{}` button in the editor

Comment: @MatthewBracewell To post code, it will wrap automatically. Once you past it in, select all of it and click on the preformatted code icon `{}` which moves it over four spaces. You can also break any lines yourself if you wish. Scroll bars will automatically be added to code.

Comment: @DerekF I had a need to look at tasks related to the Parent Project or the Project (child) the Or statement allowed this then the AND statement worked for exactly what i needed. Full code shown below now in question

Comment: `if( std.getRecord().Id != null )` should read `if( std.getId() != null )`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can request the Id from the `getRecord()` method of the `StandardController` class.

Instead of this, you should use the `getId()` method from the `StandardController` class.

Like this:

```
where TaskRay__Project__c =: std.getId() && TASKRAY__trIsMilestone__c == 'TRUE'];
```